# How can I trigger the notification when URL link is updated(when new product arrived)?

Tags: javascript, flutter, firebase, react-native, notifications

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, Text, ScrollView, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

const App = () => {
  const [recalledProducts, setRecalledProducts] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const scrollViewRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchRecalledProducts();
  }, [currentPage]);

  const fetchRecalledProducts = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`https://www.gov.uk/product-safety-alerts-reports-recalls?page=${currentPage}`);
      const html = await response.text();
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);

      const products = [];

      $('.gem-c-document-list__item').each((index, element) => {
        const title = $(element).find('.gem-c-document-list__item-title').text().trim();
        const summary = $(element).find('.gem-c-document-list__item-description').text().trim();
        const date = $(element).find('.gem-c-document-list__item-metadata').text().trim();

        products.push({ title, summary, date });
      });

      setRecalledProducts(products);
      setIsLoading(false);

      scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ y: 0, animated: true });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Hata:', error);
      setIsLoading(false);
    }
  };

  const handleNextPage = () => {
    setCurrentPage(currentPage + 1);
  };

  const handlePrevPage = () => {
    if (currentPage > 1) {
      setCurrentPage(currentPage - 1);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
        ref={scrollViewRef}
        onScroll={(event) => {
          const { y } = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset;
          scrollViewRef.current.scrollTo({ x: 0, y, animated: true });
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.headerContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.headerText}>PRODUCT RECALLS</Text>
        </View>
        {isLoading ? (
          <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#666666" />
            <Text style={styles.loadingText}>Loading</Text>
          </View>
        ) : (
          recalledProducts.map((product, index) => (
            <View key={index}>
              <Text style={styles.title}>{product.title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.summary}>{product.summary}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.date}>{product.date}</Text>
              {index < recalledProducts.length - 1 && <View style={styles.divider} />}
            </View>
          ))
        )}
      </ScrollView>
      <View style={styles.pageContainer}>
        <View style={styles.pageBox}>
          <Text style={styles.pageText}>Page: {currentPage}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
      {currentPage > 1 && (
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.backButton} onPress={handlePrevPage}>
          <Text style={styles.backButtonText}>Back</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.nextButton} onPress={handleNextPage}>
        <Text style={styles.nextButtonText}>Next</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#d9d9d9',
  },
  contentContainer: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    paddingTop: 20,
    paddingHorizontal: '10%',
  },
  headerContainer: {
    backgroundColor: '#bfbfbf',
    paddingVertical: 10,
    marginBottom: 10,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: '#333333',
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginBottom: 2,
    color: '#333333',
  },
  summary: {
    fontSize: 12,
    marginBottom: 0,
    color: '#555555',
    lineHeight: 16,
    textAlign: 'justify',
  },
  date: {
    fontSize: 10,
    fontStyle: 'italic',
    color: '#888888',
    textAlign: 'right',
  },
  nextButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
    right: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#666666',
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  nextButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  backButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
    left: 20,
    backgroundColor: '#666666',
    paddingVertical: 8,
    paddingHorizontal: 16,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  backButtonText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  divider: {
    height: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    marginVertical: 5,
  },
  pageContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    width: '100%',
    paddingBottom: 20,
  },
  pageBox: {
    backgroundColor: '#bfbfbf',
    padding: 10,
    borderRadius: 5,
  },
  pageText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  loadingContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  loadingText: {
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    marginTop: 10,
    color: '#666666',
  },
});

export default App;
```

```
/**
 * @format
 */

import {AppRegistry,Platform} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

import PushNotification from "react-native-push-notification";

// Must be outside of any component LifeCycle (such as `componentDidMount`).
PushNotification.configure({
  // (optional) Called when Token is generated (iOS and Android)
  onRegister: function (token) {
    console.log("TOKEN:", token);
  },

  // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
  onNotification: function (notification) {
    console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);

    // process the notification

    // (required) Called when a remote is received or opened, or local notification is opened
    
  },

  // (optional) Called when Registered Action is pressed and invokeApp is false, if true onNotification will be called (Android)
  onAction: function (notification) {
    console.log("ACTION:", notification.action);
    console.log("NOTIFICATION:", notification);

    // process the action
  },

  // (optional) Called when the user fails to register for remote notifications. Typically occurs when APNS is having issues, or the device is a simulator. (iOS)
  onRegistrationError: function(err) {
    console.error(err.message, err);
  },

  // IOS ONLY (optional): default: all - Permissions to register.


  // Should the initial notification be popped automatically
  // default: true
  popInitialNotification: true,

  /**
   * (optional) default: true
   * - Specified if permissions (ios) and token (android and ios) will requested or not,
   * - if not, you must call PushNotificationsHandler.requestPermissions() later
   * - if you are not using remote notification or do not have Firebase installed, use this:
   *     requestPermissions: Platform.OS === 'ios'
   */
  
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

First of all, I shared App.js and my index.js file below. I pull the products listed on the site with the aprse method from the URL link in the App.js file and show them to the user. I can buy tokens from firebase with index.js and send notifications manually, but what I want is to be automatically updated when the site is updated, that is, when a new product arrives. How can I do this? I really need your help.